# How to connect MongoDB using MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb

I have created MongoDB Atlas account, and tried to connect.
But got the error below.

MongoDB connection error MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00-c487z.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-00-c487z.mongodb.net:27017 closed .......]

Here is my code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const Data = require('./data');
const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();
const dbRoute = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<Password>@cluster0-c487z.mongodb.net/fullstack_app';
mongoose.connect(dbRoute, {useNewUrlParser: true});
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the database'));
db.on('error', console.log.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error'));
router.post('/putData', (req, res) => {
    let data = new Data();
    const { id, message } = req.body;
    if ((!id && id !== 0) || !message) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        error: 'INVALID INPUTS',
      });
    }
    data.message = message;
    data.id = id;
    data.save((err) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
      return res.json({ success: true });
    });
  });

  app.use('/api', router);
  app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to your atlas account and click "Connect" on the "Clusters" tab
[image]

Select "Connect application"

[image]

Choose language and driver version (node.js driver 3.0+ on the screenshot) and copy the connection string to use in your application:

[image]

Ensure you read and comprehend the smallprint - you will need to replace login and password with actual values.

Then go to "Network" tab and click "Add IP":

[image]

Then click "Add current IP" to access the cluster from your current system or add an IP of your server that hosts your application manually:

[image]